# Count number of records returned by temp table - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My script is as below

```
CREATE TABLE #t (Id int, Name varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #t VALUES (1, 'A')
INSERT INTO #t VALUES (1, 'B')
INSERT INTO #t VALUES (1, 'C')
INSERT INTO #t VALUES (1, 'D')
INSERT INTO #t VALUES (2, 'E')

SELECT COUNT(0)FROM (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM #t GROUP BY Id) a
```

but I am getting an error

> Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
>   No column name was specified for column 1 of 'A'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use a subquery, all the columns need to given names:

```
SELECT COUNT(0)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(0) as cnt FROM #t GROUP BY Id
     ) a;
```

However, a simpler way to write this is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM #t;
```

Actually, this isn't *exactly* the same.  Your version will count `NULL` values but this does not.  The exact equivalent is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) + MAX(CASE WHEN id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM #t;
```